# Rmarkdown displaying results even when I use results = 'hide'

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, hide

I have a weird situation - and I apologize in advance, but this issue doesn't lend itself to a reproducible example. Here is the situation

Here is the skeleton of the problem

```
Chunk 1  
Chunk 2  
...  
Chunk N-1
```

Then I have a chunk which is basically of the form:

```
{r chunkname, results = 'asis'}
f <- function(x){
y <- some computation on x
return(y)
}

T1 <- f(A)
T2 <- f(B)
```

According to the structure, nothing should get displayed, but when I knit the Rmarkdown file, both T1 and T2 appear. This is true even if I use results = 'hide'.

Now the weirder part. If I put the offending chunk in an Rmarkdown file by itself, it behaves as it should, and does not display T1 and T2.

The preceding chunks (Chunk1 - ChunkN-1) all run exactly as expected - no weird behaviors.

Last clue - not sure if it matters. The function in the offending chunk involves generating a table with gt.

I'm sorry - I realize there isn't a lot to go on here, but this is a chunk in the middle of several thousand lines of code - all of which run fine. And, when the offending code is on its own, it behaves.

Comment: What output do you have in your YAML?

Comment: I have it set as output: html_document

This is true in both the big (not working) file, and the small test file where it runs fine

Comment: Try a few things to try to rule them out--if you haven't already. One or any of these may fix the issue. 1) Add `include=F` to the chunk options. (This causes the file to still use the code, but renders nothing when knit). 2) Clear the `knitr` cache. 3) Copy all of the code; save it in a new RMD file.

Comment: @Kat - thank you for taking the time to offers suggestions. New file and cache did not work, but include=F allowed me to hide the output. I also found this blog post from 5 years ago praising the value of "include=F": https://yihui.org/en/2017/11/knitr-include-false/

It's still quite unsatisfying for me to not understand what is causing this weird behavior - but at least I have working code. I guess we can't know all things!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found an aswer to this problem. I left something seemingly innocuous out of my post.

The original code looked basically like:

```
{r chunkname, results = 'asis'}
f <- function(x){
y <- some computation on x
return(y)
}

T1 <- f(A)
T2 <- f(B)

save(T1)
save(T2)
```

Note that in my original post, I failed to include the "save(T1)" part. Well, it turned out that was the problem. If, instead of `save(T1)` I substitute `temp <- save(T1)`, the issue disappears.

I don't understand why a `save` was causing something to be displayed. I also don't really understand what "assigning" the `save` action to the variable `temp` even means. But - it suppresses the output of the results to the kintted file.